# Holo fast scroll look on old devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-holo-everywhere, fastscroll

### About my app

I have an app that has the holo look.

For pre-Honeycomb devices, I just backported some elements of the Holo theme.

Working with themes, styles and attrs is ok for CheckBox, RadioButton ...

### What I'm trying to do

I use a [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) to displays a lot of item. I want to enable fast scroll on my [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) and I want it to have the holo look.

### My problem

I have some difficulties integrating the fast scroll [Drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) it into my app theme.

### What I've tried so far

1. **Looking for libraries that does this.** [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) was
   promising but doesn't handle that.
2. **Tried to do it myself:**

I just added those drawables:

[image] [image]

Then also added this drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_default_holo" />
</selector>
```

Added this in my **`attrs.xml`**:

```
<attr name="fastScrollThumbDrawable" format="reference" />
```

I added this in my **`themes.xml`**:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>
</style>
```

This theme is properly set to my app in the **`Manifest.xml`**:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

Keep in mind that `android:fastScrollThumbDrawable` [doesn't exist pre-honeycomb](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fastScrollTrackDrawable).

---

I hope you can help me solve this. :)

**Update :**

Looks like fast scroll support has been added to [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) a few hours ago:

> https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/commit/34561e48339bf6a3e0307d2d35fc4c5ac8409310

I will check that out. :)

Comment: have the HoloEverywhere solved your problem?

Comment: I didn't try to integrate HoloEverywhere in my app but if the owner accepted the pull request it is certainly that it works. I looked how they did it and it looks like it's pretty heavy. Too much for me to integrate it in my app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the `android:fastScrollThumbDrawable` but I not know why it isn't working, so searching on web i found [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/zhuqiang/archive/2013/01/22/2871318.html) a hard code solution, I not know if it works on old API like you need, but in my case was solved the problem. Note I'm using API 18 like target and a device with API 17 to test.

the code:

```
try {
    Field f = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mFastScroller");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Object o = f.get(<<your listView here>>);
    f = f.getType().getDeclaredField("mThumbDrawable");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Drawable drawable = (Drawable) f.get(o);
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.<<your thumb drawable here can be a selector>>);
    f.set(o, drawable);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>
</style>
```

to something like this, it seemes that you forgot an antribute there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="listviewfastscrollstyle" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:fastScrollTrackDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Now it should work :)

Best Regards

safari

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this doesn't work. Keep in mind that the android:fastScrollTrackDrawable doesn't exist pre-honeycomb. Any other ideas ?

Comment: oh im sorry  forgot about that, your right.... hmm ill think over something new..